# How can I adjust for swiping in from an edge when my touchscreen has a bezel?

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen

My laptop has a touchscreen.  Windows 8 is designed for touchscreen.

Score.

But the problem is that many *important* Windows 8 gestures, by default, watch for swipes that cross the boundary from outside of the touch surface.

My problem is that my laptop's touchscreen has a *bezel*, so I cannot swipe in from outside of the touch surface cleanly.  I can try to squeeze my finger in the crack between the bezel and the screen, then swipe, but that is completely unreliable, working maybe 10% of the time.

What can I do to adjust this?

---

Its a Dell Studio 17, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Mentioning the exact model might help in case someone has found a workaround for it already. Otherwise with older hardware and a newer OS, unless the manufacturer releases drivers/software, it might be difficult to make the two work together properly.

Comment: I just swipe from the bazel to the screen and it works fine. Capacitive touch screen can actually start sensing your finger when it is falling on to the screen from the bazel.

Comment: @karan updated.

Comment: @billc.cn hmm, maybe I'm overthinking it?  Will try that approach tomorrow.

Comment: @Will: No.  The bezel is too thick, so my finger impacts the screen too far in from the edge.

Answer (score 1):

I have a screen with a thick bezel (maybe 1mm above the screen) and I have no troubles getting the swipe-from-edge thing working. A trick is to start your finger at the very edge of the screen that you can touch, so the side of your finger is against the bezel. This should register and open the Charm Bar (etc). However I've also been able to simply swipe from the bezel onto the screen at a fairly high speed and gotten it to register. But try starting from the very edge of the *screen*, not bezel, if that doesn't work.

Make sure you swipe quickly, I'm pretty sure that's a factor of how it detects a "swipe" in this/most contexts.

Comment: :/ I'm in the same situ, but that doesn't work for me.  Am looking for tweaks,

Comment: @Will odd, my laptop is about as old as yours (so it should have similarly out of date multitouch). Is normal multitouch relatively responsive?  Other touch interactions work fine, well calibrated, little to no lag?

Comment: No, the touchscreen actually is better than it was in 7, but the edge swipes don't work.

Answer (score 0):

One work around is to recalibrate the touch screen, touching inside (towards the ceter) of the points that are displayed. Then, when you swipe in from an edge, windows will see it as coming in from off screen. The down side is that any touches near the edge will be slightly off.

Answer (score 0):

If your graphics card and drivers support it, you may be able to scale down the width and hight enough to give you a slide in area.

[Here](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/vista-enterprise-desktop/dealing-with-the-bezel-issue-and-windows-8/) is a more detailed article about this.